# set a combobox value in default cell editor and renderer JTable

Tags: swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I want to select a value in a default cell editor combobox initially. When i set that inside renderer or editor the combo always shows the same value even if the user changes it, since i am setting the value in renderer. How to set the combobox value in renderer and allow the user to make changes to the combo? below is my code:

```
public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, final int column) {
if (column == 1) {    
    TableCellRenderer renderer = new TableCellRenderer() {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1,boolean arg2, boolean arg3, int row, int col) {             
            String text="";
            Component  comp;


            if(lovArray[row]!=null && lovArray[row].split("\\|").length>1)
            {
                JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(lovArray[row].split("\\|"));
                comp =combo;
                //combo.setSelectedItem(values[row]);
            }
            else
            {
                comp = CustomTable.super.getCellRenderer(row, col).getTableCellRendererComponent(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, row, col);
            }                               

            return comp;
        }
    };      

    return renderer;
}

return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
```

}

in the above code i am going to display a combo only if the values for that particular row has multiple values delimited by "|". otherwise am going to return the default renderer.

I also want to set the combo value to a particular value from an array. but since am setting inside renderer its always displayng the same value even if the user changes the combo value. how to fix this?

Comment: a combo as renderer doesn't make much sense: it's usage essence is to choose a value from its dropdown, but the dropdown will never be visible in a rendering component. Also: don't re-create a new renderer/rendering component in every call to getCellRenderer, instead re-use the same instance

Comment: @kleopatra i didnt get what you mean by "but the dropdown will never be visible in a rendering component". I am able to get combobox dropdown in all the cells wherever necessary according to my code. The thing is i need to change the preselected value from combo when its getting displayed. I am able to get the dropdown and make a selection. but after the selection the combobox just displays one fixed value that i set inside the renderer. I want the cells to look like a drop down box bcoz the user should know that they can select a value from it. any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry. It's my mistake that i made in another part of the code. In my custom table i have overriden the following:

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
{
if(col==0)
{
    return variables[row];
}
else if(col==1)
{
    return values[row];
}

return null;
}
```

this made the comboBox at column=1 to always display one specific item. Now I have removed this. and the combo box value in the cell editor is changing according to user selection.

I have removed the renderer and decided to display it as a default cell itself. when the user clicks on it I have made a combo box in a DefaultCellEditor allowing the user to select a value from the drop down.

Cheers.